# Upload issue in MIME type while file open

Tags: html, database, internet-explorer, file-upload

I have an issue when i try to upload an attachment to my application.
When the file is still open on my computer and i try to upload it, i get an application/octet-stream MIME type instead of application/sword. But when i close it, there is no error while uploading.

Files what have a problem are excel or word files and are stocked in database.
The configuration of the database allows to save in binaries and text (depending of the file)

Obviously, i could fix it by closing it. But i would like to understand how/why my file is uploaded in another MIME type.

EDIT : The browser is IE9 (compatibility with IE7) and the OS is windows 7.
It happends on each computer of my service. (with the same configuration)

Comment: This could be a browser bug rather than anything we can do somethinbg about. Can you add what browser and operating system this is on, and whether it happens with other browsers, too? The question could also use some better tagging, I'd suggest `html` `file-upload` and the name of your operating system/browser (and perhaps the server-side programming language, too.)

Comment: Does it also happen with other browsers?

Comment: I couldn't tell you... Application only run on IE. Log in doesn't work with other browsers.

Comment: Given that Internet Explorer is closed source and this is likely to be a bug in IE (or the OS, or the MIME type detection library IE is using...) I'm not sure whether you will ever get a satisfactory response to this. My guess would be that IE tries to sniff the MIME type by reading the first couple of bytes in the file, and that it can't/won't do that when it is already opened by someone else.

Comment: It confirms what i fund. But there is one last thing i didn't write : if i have it opened on my computer, a collegue can upload it without error. I guess there is a .tmp file created on my computer when i opened the file. I would like to know how the .tmp file can do that.